# android: can't see log output

Tags: android, console, logging

I try to log some text using Log.v or Log.e but I can't see the text anywhere in the eclipse console.

What am I missing? thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Log output doesn't go to the eclipse console.  You will want to either use the `DDMS` perspective or open the `LogCat` view from `Window->Show View->Other->Android->LogCat`, for example `Log.d("message","false")` will be shown in LogCat as this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The text isn't shown on the console, its shown on the logcat which is not visible by default. To enable it:

Click Window>ShowView>Other>under Android folder, select logcat

or hit alt+shift+q then release all buttons, then hit q. The Show View window should pop up. Under the Android folder, select logcat.

Answer (score 1):

However, the logcat of Eclipse doesn't work well. Sometimes it crashes without any apparent reason. You should use DDMS that can be integrated in Eclipse GUI and works pretty well.